# @SuppressLint and @TargetApi not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, lint

Prerequisites: Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 on OS X
Problem: I want to build my app for Android SDK 10. Eclipse seems not to recognize `@SuppressLint` and `@TargetApi` from androidannotations and does not allow me to use code from SDK 14.
- In AndroidManifest.xml I set both `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` to `10`
- In file project.properties I set `target=android-10`
- In Project Properties > Android Lint Preferences I set NewApi severity to "Warning"
- annotations.jar is in Android Dependencies folder
- class screenshot, I tried various variants here. Also I tried Clean, Build, Reopen...
[image: errors]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution...

- set Project Build Target higher (in my case I set 4.1.2)
- after that Eclipse suggested me some variants for "*Field requires API level 14 (current min is 10): android.view.View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION*" and I chose `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)` for the method `hideNavigationBar`